# Sencha CMD Performance on Windows 13x slower than Mac

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I posted this to the Sencha Forums with no response and I'm wondering if this is just my issue and I should create a sencha ticket, or others see the same problem.  When I create the simplest of sencha scaffolds (sencha generate app...) I see a one second build time for "Sencha App Watch" but same project on windows takes a very long 13 Seconds. (details below).

My questions is does anyone else see slow build times on windows? it seems to be slow in the css processing.  I've verified this by turning off css in build.properties.

---

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?310264-Performance-of-sencha-app-watch-disappointedly-slow&p=1132752#post1132752

Performance of sencha app watch disappointedly slow

I have a relatively small app that takes about 15 seconds to rebuild on JavaScript changes on my relatively new top end MacBook Pro 15. When I run the same "sencha app watch" on a high end 6 core desktop with a super fast ssd (twice as fast as MacBook ssd, core i7 4x the speed of MacBook). Perfect only improves a little (2 seconds faster).

Is this expected?

**UPDATE 4/17/2016
Unfortunately I've found if I turn css gen off bad things happen so I want to leave it on which means I need an answer to this. I've just discovered that when I run the same SENCHA APP WATCH on my macbook (OSX) vs windows it takes just one second. I've pasted the output below. Something is very broken in windows!

OSX:
Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Appending content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/classic.json
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Waiting for changes...
[INF] Detected change to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/app/view/main/Main.js
[INF] -----------------------
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Appending content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/classic.json
[INF] merging 223 input resources into /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg/classic/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg/classic/resources
[INF] merging 18 input resources into /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg
[INF] Writing content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/sass/example/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/sass/example/bootstrap.js
[INF] writing sass content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss.tmp
[INF] Using base href : /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg/classic/resources/
[INF] Using base href : /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/build/development/SvccReg/classic/resources/
[INF] Build complete for ../../build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss
[INF] Building ../../build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Appending content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /Users/PeterKellner 1/Documents/bitbucket/svcccss/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsMac/SvccReg/classic.json
[INF] Refresh complete in 1 sec. at 12:32:35 PM
[INF] -----------------------
[INF] Waiting for changes...

WINDOWS 10
INF] Detected change to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\app\view\main\Register.js
[INF] Detected change to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\app\view\main\Register.js
[INF] Detected change to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\app\view\main\Register.js
[INF] -----------------------
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[WRN] C1000: Rhino Parse Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 object initializer => ]) -- C:\VCProject\SV
CodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\app\view\main\Register.js:110:13
[INF] Appending content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\classic.json
[INF] merging 223 input resources into C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\development\SvccReg\classic\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\development\SvccReg\classic\resources
[INF] merging 18 input resources into C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\development\SvccReg
[INF] merged 0 resources into C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\development\SvccReg
[INF] Writing content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\sass\example\bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\sass\example\bootstrap.js
[INF] writing sass content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\temp\development\SvccReg\sass\SvccReg-all.scss.tmp

[INF] appending sass content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\temp\development\SvccReg\sass\SvccReg-all.scss.t
mp
[INF] appending sass content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\build\temp\development\SvccReg\sass\SvccReg-all.scss.t
mp
[LOG] Building C:/VCProject/SVCodeCampWeb/WebAPI/ExtJSAppsWs/build/temp/development/SvccReg/sass/SvccReg-all.scss
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Appending content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJSAppsWs\apps\SvccReg\classic.json
[INF] Refresh complete in 13 sec. at 12:38:24 PM
[INF] -----------------------
[INF] Waiting for changes...

Comment: With Sencha Cmd v6.1.2.15 x64 and Ext-6.0.1 on Windows 7 (i7 950 and old HDD): `[INF] Refresh complete in 11 sec.`

Comment: @AntonKedrov that's about the same as my 13 seconds.  On Mac OSX it takes 1 second.

Comment: Yes, I wonder what makes this difference. I also tested on my home PC, which has 8-core AMD CPU and OCZ Vertex 4 SSD, and it takes 15 sec. to refresh app generated with Sencha Cmd.

Comment: Btw you have always post all the relevant information: Windows, Cmd, ExtJS versions. I have seen post about [ruby version affecting this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?309733-Preferred-Ruby-Version). But I would check what exactly happens during the build. I have found out that windows defender and windows indexing can slow some file IO actions 2-3x

Comment: It feels like it's the CSS (which I think is ruby related).  Sencha CMD is a black box to me.  I don't have any windows things (like indexing, scanning, etc.) getting in my way I'm 99.9% sure.